# My cat attacked my pet leopard gecko and the gecko is probably injured, what to do?

Tags: reptiles, medicines, injury, leopard-geckos

A few hours ago my cat got my gecko and scratched it in the neck, ear, back, and hands. She seems to be alive and moving well, but her jaw is just the tinniest bit of crooked, and she does take a while to swallow. Is my leopard gecko going to live any longer?

She has no trouble walking, but I don't know how she's doing. I already cleaned up the wounds, and stopped the blood.

Comment: I think the best option now is probably going to vet immediately. I don't think this is a proper place for emergency situation as probably no qualified vets are here.

Comment: Also even for a qualified vet it is difficult to assess the the situation without physically examining your gecko.

Answer (score 3):

I agree a vet is your best option. I’m a qualified veterinary nurse and I can tell you even a qualified vet cannot diagnose online. They will only tell you to take it to the vet.

Unfortunately it may have a broken jaw and even the scratches can be life threatening as cat scratches have a high chance of infection.

Good luck! Let us know what the vet says.